# DataTables - Only show 30 rows

Tags: c#

I have the following code that works well, it shows all the data in a table but the data is starting to get big and was wondering if there is a easy solution to only show .e.g. 30 rows using the .Taken(30) but not sure how to implement that into the script? any pointers :)

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#TEP').DataTable({
                "order": [[0, "desc"]]

            });
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have option `pageLength`, check [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/46346/how-to-show-less-than-10-rows)

```
var table = $('#TEP').DataTable({
            pageLength : 30,
            order: [0, 'desc']
            });
```